# How can I combine Num1 with Num2 with num1-num2 format?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is what I'm trying to do.

---

There's a `row`, called `Price`. **Some rows** include a range of numbers, like 200-300, or 650-700.

---

Currently, I echo `$row["Price"]`.

I'm trying to show each row that contains a range as a single number, like a `650-700` `row` show as `675`.

I understand `avg` function, but how can I make it understand my format of `number1-number2`?

Thanks !

---

Final Edit: Thanks to everyone for their contribution.

My final solution was to make a `PriceMin` and `PriceMax` column via using determinator in excel for the tables, and do it like that.

Thanks !

Comment: you should rather change your table structure and use *PriceMin* and *PriceMax* fields (and maybe *PriceFixed*, or only *PriceMin*, or same value in both fields, for fixed priced items).

Answer (score 2):

So, as I understand you are using `PHP` and your accessing your data via `mySql`? So in this case your `$row["Price"]` contains a `String` with "650-700"?

One simply way would be to explode this string in two parts and make the calculation. So e.g.:

```
$range = explode("-", $row["Price"]);
[convert string to int]
$avg = ($range[1]+$range[0]) / 2;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's not quite how you calculate an average. It think you mean `$avg = ($range[1]+$range[0]) / 2;`

Comment: Ah yes, you are right sorry. I fix it... of courcse you also have to convert the String into an int before calculating :)

Comment: In PHP, there is no need for explicit type casts.

Answer (score 0):

> There's a row, called Price. Some rows include a range of numbers, like 200-300, or 650-700.

I assume you mean you have a col called `Price' and some rows have values from 200-300? And so the type of the`Price`-col is varchar?

You could try `substring` the first number and the second number and pass these to the `avg` function, something like this

```
select avg(SUBSTRING(PriceCol, 0, LOCATE('-', PriceCol) - 1, SUBSTRING(PriceCol, LOCATE('-', 'PriceCol') + 1)) from table;
```

or

```
select avg(SUBSTRING_INDEX('PriceCol', '-', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX('PriceCol', '-', -1)) from table;
```

to make `200-300` to `avg(200,300)`.

**Note** Syntax is wrong but I don't have time now to look up the correct one, will edit later, but I think you'll get the guess

**edit**: I think I fixed syntax, also added example with `substring_index`, for both see [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should in fact change your database and make the `price` column an integer, and include columns like `max_price` and `min_price`. Or you should do this in PHP (using functions like [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and do the calculations yourself.

But, just for completion and fun, here is an all-SQL solution:

```
SELECT 
     SUBSTR(`Price`, LOCATE("-",`Price`)+1) + 
     SUBSTR(`Price`, 1, LOCATE("-",`Price`)-1) 
     / 2;
```